# Why 'continue' doesn't work within an angular foreach?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app as the following and I have a angular.forEach function where I want to skip some values with the `continue` keyword but I can't.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="test">
    test
    {{printPairs()}}
  </div>
</div>

angular.module("app", [])
       .controller("test", function($scope){
          var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

          $scope.printPairs = function(){
            angular.forEach(array, function (elem) {
              if(elem % 2 === 1){
                 continue;
              }
              //More logic  below...
            })
          };
       });
```

Someone knows why is this happening?

Comment: 'continue' doesn't work in angular.forEach()

Comment: _The continue statement terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration._ That refers to native loops, not those provided by helper functions

Comment: Because continue can be used inside the body of a traditional for loop, but not in a function passed to the forEach function of array. Just use `if (elem % 2 === 0) { // logic }`. That would be much cleaner anyway, even in a for loop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happens because you are not inside a javascript foreach statement.

But we are in a function. How you can see angular.forEach second parameter is a callback witch is called in every loop.

So to solve your problem you can just use a simple "return" to jump the current position who match with your if condition, like this:

```
angular.forEach(array, function (value, key) {
     if(1 === value % 2){
        return;
     }
     //More logic  below...
 })
```

Comment: return will break the statement

Comment: return acts the same way as continue on a regular javascript  for each